# Error in Validation of project

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-7

In clean building my project from the eclipse menu (eclipse kepler) I have this error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Validation' on project 'XXXX'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I already sought for a solution with no luck. I found loads of *javascript validation* errors but no *Validation* ones.
I have manually configured eclipse to access the jdk 1.7. I have `maven nature` and the `dynamic web module` facet enabled. In fact running `maven clean install` either from command line or from eclipse works fine.

Comment: Is turning off the validation an option?

Comment: Nope, tried, but does not deploy giving again a null pointer exception

Answer (score 3):

Just removing folder [workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.validation and restarting eclipse solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Go to -> Eclipse Workspace-> .metadata -> .plugins
find the "org.eclipse.wst.validation" delete this folder.

Then exit eclipse and open again this will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of (not) knowledge I had to reinstall eclipse (therefore it was probably a problem with the eclipse instance, not the workspace configuration), I couldn't find the problem and had to keep on with the project.